# Adding prepare statement results broken code

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Before prepare statement when I searching by ID it's working, but after adding prepare statement results are: ID doesn't exist!

This is my code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <label for=""><h4>Search by ID</h4></label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input name="search" type="number" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button name="submit" class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
            </span>
        </div>
<hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Ime</th>
                        <th>Prezime</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>

                <?php

                if(isset($_POST['search'])) {

                $search_id = $_POST['search'];

                mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");
                $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, "SELECT id, ime, prezime FROM anketa WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1");

                if(isset($stmt)) {

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $search_id);

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ank_id, $ank_ime, $ank_prezime);

                    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

                }

                if(!$stmt) {
                    die("QueryFailed" . mysqli_error($connection));
                }

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {

                    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)):

                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>{$ank_id}</td>";
                            echo "<td>{$ank_ime}</td>";
                            echo "<td>{$ank_prezime}</td>";      
                            echo "<td><a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href='search.php?source=edit&edit={$ank_id}'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i> Edit</a></td>";
                            echo "<td><a class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Delete?'); \" href='search.php?delete={$ank_id}'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i> Delete</a></td>";

                    endwhile;

                    } else {

                        echo "ID doesn't exist!";

                    }

                } 

                ?>

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php

if(isset($_GET['delete'])) {

$ank_id = $_GET['delete'];

if(isset($_SESSION['user_role'])) {

if($_SESSION['user_role'] == 'admin' || 'user_role'] == 'superadmin') {

$the_anketa_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['delete']);

$query = "DELETE FROM anketa WHERE id = {$ank_id} ";
$delete_anketa = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
header("Location: search.php");

}

}

}

?>

</form>
 </div>

<?php
if(isset($_GET['source'])) {
$source = $_GET['source'];
if($source = 'edit') {
include "includes/edit.php";
} elseif($source = 'submit') {
header("Location: search.php");
}
} 
?>

<?php
} else {
echo "<script>alert('No access!')</script>";
}
?>
```

I don't know if problem is prepare statement or code for delete, because there is no prepare statement yet?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You have a lot of code there that is not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I will do that in the future.

Comment: If you edit your question and remove all that HTML stuff (and everything else that is not important), you'll get faster and better answers for this question.

Comment: I edited as much as I could, I hope that is ok now... I'm afraid if edit something more the problem will not be displayed...

Comment: Then test it! Reduce your code to the minimum and see if the error still happens. If not, find out which part of the code is responsible. Once you can reduce the code to the minimum, the error is much easier to find.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) is always returning zero.

PHP documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

You may need to call mysqli_stmt_store_result() first before you can get that function to return the correct value.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I understand you well, I did this:
if(isset($stmt)) {
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $search_id);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $ank_id, $ank_ime, $ank_prezime);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
}
I try many other combination with this function but no results...